# Can't locate cause of "wrong parameter count for mysql_query()"

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to put together a plugin script that takes a range of values from various locations including csv and strings them together to update existing rows in my db. It's designed to update prices for WP Ecommerce, when you start with just a sku and the new price. The first query retrieves the additional info I need from the db, and the string puts the data in the correct order.

I've got the values in a string ready to import. But I keep getting the error in the title: "wrong parameter count for mysql_query()". Can anyone help me out? Have I done something fundamentally wrong here?

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `post_id` = (SELECT `post_id` FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `meta_value` = '$var') AND `meta_key` = '_wpsc_price'") or die(mysql_error()); 

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    //Collates all the info for the line of data we need...
    $my_string = ($row['meta_id'].$row['post_id'].$row['meta_key'].$data[$index-1]);
    global $wpdb; 

$update = mysql_query("REPLACE TABLE 'wp_postmeta' VALUES ($my_string)",
        mysql_real_escape_string($meta_id), 
        mysql_real_escape_string($post_id), 
        mysql_real_escape_string($meta_key),
        mysql_real_escape_string($meta_value)); 
}
```

Comment: Might need a full copy of the code to be sure all the braces and , and " line up

Comment: I'm confident everything lines up. I've got the data I need, tested through echo. I just need it to get in the db.

Comment: Can you show us what echo of $update shows?

Comment: I can't echo $update without getting the same error.

Comment: sorry I meant the query that is produced for making $update - eg pull out the query and echo it to confirm and then we can play spot the missing whatsit

Comment: or at worst, whats in $my_String

Comment: UPDATE TABLE 'wp_postmeta' VALUES 129992012_wpsc_price4 DXL*ROS32 UPDATE TABLE 'wp_postmeta' VALUES 151142247_wpsc_price8

Comment: That's what we get when we echo update. All the info is there for the query. Seems it's not formatted as I would expect though? Presumably mysql wants to see the data delimited? Also, this is two queries, looped.

Comment: OK so youre code isnt the real code.. as it says "replace table" .. but.. you only have 1 column in your table?

Comment: I've changed the code since posting. It was REPLACE. I am trying to replace the 1 line in the table the meta_id, post_id, and meta_key  correlates to.

Comment: so chances are you either need to explain which 1 field you're updating, or, fields, and then if its more than 1 field, add the commas, as well as qotation marks in.. as well as where id=<id you got before> so its only updating the 1 line

Comment: plus, if you're updating the 3 fields you look at putting in my_string - you arent changing the data - so whats the point of the update? (Im not understanding there)

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I only want to update the last column. I had in mind from that start that I needed to get all the data in order to find the correct row, and it followed on that I then use it in the update - but I just need it to pinpoint my row. Good stuff.  Will do some jigging. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So really your query goes

```
update 'wp_postmeta' set datafield = \"".$data[$index-1]."\"
where meta_id=\"".$row['meta_id']."\" 
and post_id=\"".$row['post_id']."\"
```

changing the name of datafield to whichever it should be

Comment: My god, I was about to go crazy with this. I've been working on this plugin for a week and this bit for 24 hours. The code above is the solution - with the exception of using ` rather than ' to define the db table and column. Beautiful. A much more elegant solution to what I had in mind. Thanks Bugfinder! Thanks also Spontifixus for your input: think you were more or less thinking along the same lines as well.

Comment: Yes the mysql query things are depreciated, but, at the same time means your code will run on more versions out there.. is it the right way to do it? shrug.. I try not to judge things like that, usually get shouted at.. so, if its now happy - please mark as answered

Comment: I know, but presumably if I remain using the current versions of everything I have the deprecation wont affect me - my webhost has been using the same versions for yonks and refuse to update and I don't plan to update any of the site once I've deployed it. Again, thanks for your help. How do I mark as answered?

Answer (score 0):

The `mysql` extension is deprecated and its use is strongly discouraged. In addition, `mysql_query()` does not accept query placeholders *at all*, it accepts one or two parameters only — query string and optional connection handle. *In addition*, you're building a very weird value in `$my_string` which then you just dump into your query string. It is hard for me to even imagine what you're trying to accomplish by that.

Comment: I want the data in the string to go in the database.

Answer (score 0):

[PHP's mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) is expecting one or two parameters. What you want to do is something like

```
$queryString = sprintf("REPLACE TABLE 'wp_postmeta' VALUES %s, %s, %s, %s",
    mysql_real_escape_string($meta_id), 
    mysql_real_escape_string($post_id), 
    mysql_real_escape_string($meta_key),
    mysql_real_escape_string($meta_value));
$update = mysql_query($queryString);
```

That code is untested - just so you get the general idea.

Comment: Evaluate the result of the query. I am pretty sure that this is not valid SQL you are using to update the wp_postmeta table.

Comment: Try `UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_id='%1s', post_id='%2s', meta_key='%3s', meta_value='%4s' WHERE meta_id='%1s'`

Comment: thanks. Will give this a go if the solution above fails. Think I was approaching this the wrong way.